# Не записывает текст в bat-файл С++

Tags: c++, bat

Решил написать самую обычную программу, которая будет создавать файл, в него вписывать команду .bat, а там уже запускать её X кол-во раз. Но выдает error.
Объясните почему.

```
ofstream file("test2.bat");
file << "@echo off\n@:loop\n@start **путь к файлу**  :loop";
file.close;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    system( **путь к файлу** );

cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: Ну что за манечка задавать вопросы "догадайся сам"... Какую ошибку и кто выдает? Компилятор, работающая программа? Дайте **всю** информацию.

Comment: `file.close;`???

Comment: Скобки `()` забыли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file.close();
```

является функцией, добавьте `()`